# Adding authentication to outbound http requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-web

I have a rest web service that is implemented using spring boot starter web.
 This service acts as a client to another application that requires authentication to make calls to it.
Calls made from the client to the server are using `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`.
**Is there a way to come up with a solution to add authentication headers to outbound requests at one single point before they are sent out?**
I don't want to add headers in each of the requests separately.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc for [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) says:

> This template uses a SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory and a
>   DefaultResponseErrorHandler as default strategies for creating HTTP
>   connections or handling HTTP errors, respectively. These defaults can
>   be overridden through
>   HttpAccessor.setRequestFactory(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory)

So I would take SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory and override its [prepareConnection(..)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html#prepareConnection-java.net.HttpURLConnection-java.lang.String-) method.